# Help reducing a Lisp function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a Lisp function which returns either the MAX of two values, or the MIN of two values.  Right now my code has some relatively complex expressions to evaluate VALUE1 and VALUE2.

```
(defun treemax (bilist &optional ismin)
  (cond
    ;; Compute minimum
    (ismin (min (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1) (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2)))
    ;; Compute maximum
    (t (max (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1) (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2)))))
```

The problem here is that COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1 and COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2 actually take up many many lines of code.  I would really like to not repeat them.  Is there a more efficient way of calling this?

Essentially what I'm trying to do is a unary-if on functions rather than values.  If you are familiar with C or its variants, essentially the concept I'm looking for is:

```
((ismin ? min : max) COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1 COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2)
```

Whereby I conditionally select which function to send the arguments to.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I don't recall Lisp syntax so i won't try to guess the exact answer with code, but the answer to your "Is there a more efficient way of calling this?" question is "absolutely yes". You need to create a function which returns a min or max function as a result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(defun treemax (bilist &optional ismin)
    (funcall (if ismin #'min #'max) 
             (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1) 
             (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2)))
```

Comment: Congrats on breaking 2k with this answer! :-D

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: Thanks, I was saving it for quite a bit :)

Answer (score 9):

Surely, this is better:

```
(defun treemax (bilist &optional (op #'max))
  (funcall op (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1) (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2)))
```

Then, simply pass in `#'min` as argument 2 if you want to use `min` instead.

(Of course, zakovyrya's answer works too.)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you need to write the same code more than once, use a function to capture the code and then call it more than once.

```
(defun treemax (bilist &optional ismin)
  (cond
     (ismin (min (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1) (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2)))
     (t     (max (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1) (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2)))))
```

-->

```
(defun treemax (bilist &optional ismin)
  (flet ((f1 () (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1))
         (f2 () (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2))))
    (cond
       (ismin (min (f1) (f2)))
       (t     (max (f1) (f2))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the things that Lisp is very good at. You can assign functions to variables and then pass arguments to them with `apply` or `funcall` (and in Scheme it's actually even easier). Here's an example:

```
(defun treemax (bilist &optional ismin)
  (let ((op (if ismin #'min #'max)))
    (funcall op (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1) (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2))))
```

(You could of course also just bind `COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1` and `COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2` to variables, but that would still create more repetition.)